# Compare the Euclidean distance of two lists of tuples with fewer comparisons python

Tags: python, list, tuples, coordinates

I am trying to calculate the Euclidean distance of two list of tuples with the threshold of 4 . If the threshold is less than a particular value then increment the counter . Each tuple is the x,y,z coordinate of the point . Is there anyway i can lower of the comparison of list1 with list2 ..

```
  X = [ (1,2,3),(2,3,4), (4,5,6) ]
  Y = [ (1,2,2) , (3,4,5),(6,7,8) ]
  from math import sqrt
  dist_X = [ sqrt((p[0] - 0)**2 + (p[1] - 0)**2 + (p[2] - 0)**2) for p in X]
  dist_Y = [ sqrt((p[0] - 0)**2 + (p[1] - 0)**2 + (p[2] - 0)**2) for p in Y]
  for x in dist_X:
     print (x ,  [ i for i,y in enumerate(dist_Y) if abs(x-y) <= 4])
```

I was thinking of first calculating the Euclidean distance of each point with the origin (0,0,0) so that both the lists now contain the points that are close to each other but it didnt work because its a scalar value .. Am i going in the right direction?

EDIT

```
   visited1 = [ (1,2,3),(2,3,4), (4,5,6) ]
   visited2   = [ (1,2,2) , (3,4,5),(6,7,8) ]
    def euclidean(a,b):
        return sqrt((a[0] - b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2+(a[2]-b[2])**2)
   comparison = 0
   for i,j in enumerate(visited2):
     for k,l in enumerate(visited1):
         if euclidean(visited2[i],visited1[k]) < 4:
                 count += 1
         comparison += 1
```

In this every element of the list1 is compared with every element in the list2 .. I want to know if there is a way i can minimise the comparisons given the points(x,y,z) that i have?

Comment: what exactly do you want to detect? Could you give the expected answer for your example and explain it?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of the Euclidean distance between two lists (each comprised of multiple coordinates)?

Comment: I want to calculate the euclidean distance between the atoms of list 1 with list 2 and if the distance is less than 4 i need these values but the i dont want that every element of list1 compares with every element in list2 .. Rather i need a way that lowers the comparisons like any pre computations like the one i did above. That was just an example .. For instance skip the values we know are too close to each other

Comment: That still doesn't define what the Euclidean distance between the two is or means—or is the real problem that you're trying to define it and don't know how? You can optimize it later after you've implemented something that calculates whatever it turns out to be. P.S. When you reply to someone's comment, please put @their_user_name in the text somewhere so they'll be notified that you have done so.

Comment: @martineau I have edited my question

Comment: It seems that the distance between molecules is the minimum distance between every pair of atoms in each. Seems to me the only thing to avoid having to do that as much as possible is to be able to skip pair of molecules. This could be done by calculating either the bounding box or bounding sphere for each molecule and then use that to skip any pair of them that couldn't possibly be that close. This would only make it faster if there are enough atoms in the molecules to make the overhead worthwhile. Regardless, you don't need to do the `sqrt()`—just compare squared distance to the threshold**2.

Answer (score 4):

One precomputatiion that can sometimes speed things up are [kd-trees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html). I ran a quick test against brute force and found that they can be quite a bit faster for larger lists:

```
# n = 10
# trees                 0.08512560 ms
# brute                 0.01425540 ms
# n = 100
# trees                 0.20338160 ms
# brute                 0.09876890 ms
# n = 1000
# trees                 6.40193820 ms
# brute                16.15429670 ms
# n = 10000
# trees               298.69653380 ms
# brute              1393.71134270 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

import types
from timeit import timeit

def setup_data(n, k):
    data = {'d1': np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, 3)),
            'd2': np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, 3)),
            'mx': k}
    return data

def f_trees(d1, d2, mx):
    t1 = cKDTree(d1)
    t2 = cKDTree(d2)
    return t1.count_neighbors(t2, mx)

def f_brute(d1, d2, mx):
    dist2 = np.add.outer(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', d1, d1), np.einsum('ij,ij->i', d2, d2)) - 2*np.einsum('ij, kj', d1, d2)
    return np.count_nonzero(dist2 <= mx*mx)



for n in (10, 100, 1000, 10000):
    data = setup_data(n, 4)
    ref = np.array(f_trees(**data))
    print(f'n = {n}')
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        try:
            assert np.allclose(ref, func(**data))
            print("{:16s}{:16.8f} ms".format(name[2:], timeit(
                'f(**data)', globals={'f':func, 'data':data}, number=10)*100))
        except:
            print("{:16s} apparently failed".format(name[2:]))
```

Comment: I would have proposed `KDtree` myself but you were faster!  Further,  your answer is really a well-argued answer. +1

Comment: This is a good answer (+1). I refrained from importing any fancy modules because the question was not tagged as such. But I suppose it doesn't hurt to show OP what they don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Draw this out in 2D to see how it looks.  Points that are roughly the same distance from the origin are *not* necessarily close to each other -- you have the triangle inequality backwards, there.  For instance, compare the points (0, 10), (0, 11), and (-8, -6).  They're all 10-11 units from the origin, but the last is nowhere near the other two.

If you want to know whether two points are close to each other, you need to compute the distance between those two points, not the distance to an arbitrary third point.  The problem is quadratic in complexity, not linear.

Comment: Okay but is there any way like a precomputation i can do before calculating the euclidean distance that would reduce the comparisons like the points that are close to one another are grouped together or something along these lines